# downloading facebook video with selenium

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver

I want to download the video from Facebook, and basically I need to press ctrl+s in chromedriver.
I tried with

```
        save = ActionChains(self.webdriver)
        save.send_keys(Keys.CONTROL + 's')
        save.perform()
```

But nothing happen. I can not use self.webdriver.page_source, because I want to save mp4. How can I do that?

Comment: How do you plan to click `save` after opening the `dialog box`, knowing that selenium doesn't  have control over such dialogs?

Comment: You can maybe get the url of the video and downloading it with requests `request.get(urlOfTheVideo) ` and writing it to a file